# Mahout CDbw Java Code Usage

Tags: java, validation, cluster-analysis, mahout

I installed Mahout and can run it from my Eclipse plataform. I am interested in use CDbw to evaluate clustering solutions for a particular dataset from my java Code. Given that I have a dataset in csv format and the labels from the partition, does anyone know where do I start from? I know I have to build a CDbwEvaluator, but it requires as input a Configuration and a Path, which I'm not sure how to set.

```
CDbwEvaluator cdbw = new CDbwEvaluator(configuration,path));
```

So how can i set my dataset as input and the labels for evaluation? It is my first time using mahout. I tried to find java examples of its usage but could not. If anyone could help, thanks!